# ng serve command requires to be run in an Angular project, but a project definition could not be found

Tags: angular, angular-cli, nrwl, nrwl-nx, angular-cli-v9

I am trying to create nrwl workspace project using nrwl cli.

I am following the below github instruction to create the nrwl workspace project

https://github.com/onehungrymind/angular-core-workshop

But I am getting the below error

[image]

When I checked ng version command I am seeing Angular is undefined. 
[image]

[image]

How can I fix this? Also, I don't see angular.json or angular.cli.json got created in my angular/nrwl project.

Comment: What about using `npm run start`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

i clone the repo successfully maybe some file was deleted,

try to clone again and then npm i before ng serve